# Excel - I am looking to group rows together and create a table of those grouped rows in order to sort them by specific columns

Tags: excel

I have a points list table. The basic idea is that I have an instrument in one row. Below that row is the physical point you are measuring. So lets say I have a flow control valve. There are 2 physical points associated with it. Command position and feedback position. I would like to group those 2 points points together under the instrument row and be able to sort that whole group by either device or reference number, etc. See Image for reference

[image]

I would like to sort by the device type or the reference number but would like to keep the points under the grey instrument umbrella.

I have tried "groups" but it didn't do exactly what I wanted it to do. It grouped them but didn't give me the instrument row as the header, which makes the whole thing pointless.

Comment: I guess you would need a helper column that features the name of each instrument for the respective instrument's header and physical positions rows. Then you can use the filter and filter the helper column by instrument name. You can use formulas to fill that helper column, e.g. look if instrument's cell begins with a space, then use the content of the cell above, otherwise use the content of the instruments cell.

Comment: If you would like to sort the table, you would have to turn the formula into values first.

Comment: You're showing us the final view of the data which has mixed records and fields. The answer is "don't store your data in the view" or "don't violate the rules of records and fields". You should study the basic concepts of database structure to avoid problems like this: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zfd2fg8/revision/5